# Hide span if condition with jQuery

Tags: jquery, hide

I want to make this span hide if value === 0

`<span class="amount">0</span>`

Then i make `mini-cart-remove.js` and added to header.

This is my code:

```
 (function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

    if ($('.amount') === 0 ) {
        $('.amount').hide();
    }

    });
})(jQuery);
```

But can't hide the span.

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get the text in the span and then compare it to 0, for this you can use .text()

```
if ($.trim($('.amount').text()) === '0' ) {
    $('.amount').hide();
}
```

If you want have multiple spans you'll have to loop through them to hide them

```js
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.amount').each(function(){
        if ($(this).text() === '0' ) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
      });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="amount">0</span>
<span class="amount">1</span>
<span class="amount">2</span>
<span class="amount">3</span>
<span class="amount">4</span>
```

Comment: It's correct that i have to use text(), but still don't hide the span.

Comment: Does the span appear exactly as you have it, or does it have spaces in it? Also are there many spans like that?

Comment: appear exactly as i have.
Maybe iit could be that the span appear before the jquery try to hide it?
That can be poss? or just for use document.ready if it appear it must be hide? @Musa

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle of Musa's example. It appears to be working just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/dnacb9us/

Comment: The problem is the time when the `<span> amount</span>` appear, so it never hide().
I think i had to make hide with a delay of time, could it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

I face it before cause I set display:block in my class
so, now I never set any display attribute in class 
just use show()  or hide()  to let elements display or not 
I face it before cause I set display:block in my class
so, now I never set any display attribute in class 
just use show()  or hide()  to let elements display or not

maybe you set display:block; in your .amount class?